# Not creating app.aab file from react native

Tags: react-native, android-app-bundle

I am using react native 0.55 version.
I when through the documentation of creating android app bundle from react native using the cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease.

I managed to run the commands in git bash with and without admin rights. The commands are always successful but i donot get to see the app.aab file created in my project.

Is there anything else that would need to be done for it to work, thanks in advance

Comment: where are you looking for your project?

Comment: @Konstantin the documentation tells me to check android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab

Comment: do you have anything inside the `/outputs` folder?

Comment: @Konstantin i have apk and logs folder